# Dlib Error deserializing object of type unsigned long while deserializing object of type std::string

Tags: python-3.x, dlib

I try to run a Python code for face detection using Dlib. But when I try to load the file `shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat` using the following command 
`face_detector =dlib.cnn_face_detection_model_v1('shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat')`

I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "face_detector.py", line 6, in <module>
    face_detector = dlib.cnn_face_detection_model_v1('shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat')
RuntimeError: An error occurred while trying to read the first object from the file shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.
ERROR: Error deserializing object of type unsigned long
   while deserializing object of type std::string
```

I have downloaded the shape predictor file from github: https://github.com/davisking/dlib-models

This is my Python code

```
import dlib
import cv2


face_detector = dlib.cnn_face_detection_model_v1('shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat')
```

The rest of the code is omitted because it's not necessary

I am using:
`Ubuntu 18.04` and `Python 3.6`

**UPDATE 1:**

If use the same file with the function `dlib.shape_predictor(shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat)` it runs without any problems!

It seems that there is a problem with the function `dlib.cnn_face_detection_model_v1`. Please correct me if I'm wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted Davis King on twitter and he t`shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat` is not the correct file. 
I have to load `mmod_human_face_detector.dat` file for function `dlib.cnn_face_detection_model_v1()`

It must be called like this

```
face_detector = dlib.cnn_face_detection_model_v1('mmod_human_face_detector.dat')
```